# refresh data in a Firestore Paging Adapter using Swipe Refresh Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using FirestorePagingAdapter to show data in my app but when I use Swipe Refresh Layout did not work with FirestorePagingAdapter, `swipe refresh layout.isVisible = true` in LOAD_MORE when I don't scroll
how to work with a Swipe Refresh Layout in FirestorePagingAdapter?

ViewHolde.class:

```
    class ViewHolde(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item){
            val username = item.findViewById(R.id.iduser) as TextView
            val title = item.findViewById(R.id.idtitle) as TextView
            val decription = item.findViewById(R.id.iddes) as TextView

}
```

User.class:

```
class User {
    lateinit var userphoto: StorageReference
    lateinit var username:String
    lateinit var title:String
    lateinit var notes: String
    lateinit var id: String
    var isSelected:Boolean = false
    constructor(){

    }
    constructor( id: String?,username:String?,title: String?, notes: String?) {
        this.title= title!!
        this.id= id!!
        this.username= username!!
        this.notes= notes!!
        }

}
```

RecyclerActivity.class:

```
class RecyclerActivity : AppCompatActivity(),SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    var mylist=ArrayList<User>()
    var rv:RecyclerView? = null
    var currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val str= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    private var mAuthStateListener: FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener? = null
    var db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private val notebookRef2 = db.collection("ProfileData")
    private val mQuery = notebookRef2.orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
    val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
        .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
        .setPrefetchDistance(2)
        .setPageSize(6)
        .build()
    val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(mQuery, config, User::class.java)
        .build()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler)
      rec()
    var swipeContainer = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer)as SwipeRefreshLayout
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeContainer = findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer)as SwipeRefreshLayout
    swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
        android.R.color.holo_green_light,
        android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
        android.R.color.holo_red_light);
     swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener {
            rv?.invalidate();
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

        }

    }
    override fun onRefresh() {
 Handler().postDelayed( Runnable() {
     swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);

    }, 3000);
    }
fun rec(){
    rv=findViewById(R.id.idrecycler) as? RecyclerView
    rv!!.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    db.collection("ProfileData").orderBy("title", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
            if (querySnapshot != null) {
                for(da in querySnapshot) {
                    val note = da.toObject(Note::class.java)
                    var title = note.title
                    var description = note.notes
                    var username = note!!.username
                    var id = note!!.id
                    mylist.add(User(id!!,username!!, title!!, description!!))
                }
            }
        }
    setupadapter()

}
fun setupadapter(){
    rv=findViewById(R.id.idrecycler) as? RecyclerView
    var mAdapter = object : FirestorePagingAdapter<User, ViewHolde>(options) {

        override fun onLoadingStateChanged(state: LoadingState) {
            swipeRefreshLayout2.isVisible = false
            when (state) {
                LoadingState.LOADING_INITIAL -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout2.isVisible = true
                }

                LoadingState.LOADING_MORE -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isVisible = true
                }

                LoadingState.LOADED -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isVisible = false
                }

                LoadingState.ERROR -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isVisible = false
                }

                LoadingState.FINISHED -> {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.isVisible = false
                }
            }
        }


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolde {

            var v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.iktem_list, parent, false)
            return ViewHolde(v)
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolde, position: Int, p2: User) {
            holder.username.text = mylist.get(position).username
            holder.title.text = mylist.get(position).title
            holder.decription.text = mylist.get(position).notes

        }
         }
    rv!!.adapter = mAdapter
}
}
```

ActivityRecycler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iddrawer2"
        tools:context=".RecyclerActivity">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#4C00CF"
                android:id="@+id/idtoolbar2"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"/>
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_height="460dp">
            <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/idrecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    />

            </ScrollView>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="340dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
            android:id="@+id/idnavigatuonv2"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/draw_menu"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

Comment: What do you mean through "did not work with FirestorePagingAdapter"? Do you have an error?

Comment: no, I don't have an error, but swipe refresh layout.isVisible = true in LOAD_MORE when I don't scroll, it must be false

Answer (score 0):

So I'm using the adapter to show transaction history and I have a button to show the filtered transaction history which has status == success.

On button click, I'm updating the adapter the following way:

```
baseQuery = firestore.collection("transactions")
                    .whereEqualTo("status", "success")
                    .orderBy("__name__", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<ItemTxn>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(baseQuery, config, ItemTxn.class)
            .build();

    adapter.updateOptions(options);
```

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1726#issuecomment-573033035